# (class-validator) Validate Array of Enum in Typescript

Tags: typescript, nestjs, class-validator

I would like to validate an array of enums in a DTO, however I always get a misleading message.

MY DTO

```
import { IsArray, IsEmail, IsEnum, IsIn, IsNotEmpty, IsString } from "class-validator";
import { UserAction, UserModule, UserRole } from "../enums";

import { ApiProperty } from "@nestjs/swagger";

export class CreateUserDto {

    @ApiProperty({ 
        example: 'e5c082ae-6760-4dbf-a69b-e01e94108c63', 
        description: 'The unique identifier of an user' 
    })
    @IsString()
    @IsNotEmpty()
    name: string;

    @ApiProperty({ 
        example: 'max.mustermann@sample.com', 
        description: 'The email of an user' 
    })
    @IsString()
    @IsEmail()
    @IsNotEmpty()
    email: string;

    @ApiProperty({ 
        example: '!s3cr3t!',
        description: 'The password of an user'
    })
    @IsString()
    @IsNotEmpty()
    password: string;

    @ApiProperty({ 
        example: [UserRole.Admin, UserRole.User],
        description: 'The role of an user',
        enum: UserRole,
        isArray: false
    })
    @IsIn([UserRole.Admin, UserRole.User])
    @IsEnum(UserRole)
    @IsNotEmpty()
    userRole: UserRole;

    @ApiProperty({ 
        example: [UserModule.Dashboard, UserModule.AccountManagement, UserModule.ReportManagement],
        description: 'The module of an user',
        enum: UserModule,
        isArray: true
    })
    @IsIn([UserModule.Dashboard, UserModule.AccountManagement, UserModule.ReportManagement])
    @IsEnum(UserModule, { each: true })
    @IsNotEmpty()
    userModules: UserModule[];

    @ApiProperty({
        example: [UserAction.Manage, UserAction.Create, UserAction.Read, UserAction.Update, UserAction.Delete],
        description: 'The action of an user',
        enum: UserAction,
    })
    @IsIn([UserAction.Manage, UserAction.Create, UserAction.Read, UserAction.Update, UserAction.Delete])
    @IsEnum(UserAction, { each: true })
    @IsArray()
    @IsNotEmpty()
    userActions: UserAction[];
}
```

MY POSTMAN Request Body

```
{
    "name": "David",
    "email": "david@gmail.com",
    "password": "123456",
    "userRole": "admin",
    "userModules": [ "dashboard", "account-management" ],
    "userActions": [ "manage" ]
}
```

MY POSTMAN Response

```
{
    "statusCode": 400,
    "message": [
        "userModules must be one of the following values: dashboard, account-management, report-management",
        "userActions must be one of the following values: manage, create, read, update, delete"
    ],
    "error": "Bad Request"
}
```

I don't quite understand why it tells me it must have a value of the following values, even though these values are

I have tired to create instead a own ValidatorConstraintInterface implementations, without success

Comment: Remove `@IsIn(…)`. You can add `IsArray()` and `IsEnum()`  
But is an array of enums is a good practice ? Send just Enum or just Array no ?

Answer (score 1):

```
@IsEnum(UserRole, { each: true })
```

That's how it should work.

Answer (score 0):

`IsEnum(each: true)` and `IsIn` are contradicting each other, `IsEnum(each: true)` is applcable to array, but `IsIn` to value (see documentation), remove `IsIn`.

Also `IsNotEmpty` is applicable to strings, for other types you should use `IsDefined`. For not empty array `@ArrayNotEmpty`.